# libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll missing while running c++ program

Tags: c++, compilation, codeblocks

I created a program in C++, it was just  a joke. I wanted to test the possibilities just a little. I built the program, ran it through Code::Blocks
and it worked. I headed over to the directory I saved it in, ran it from there.

> The program can't start because libstdc++-6.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I pressed OK, then another "popup"

> The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I **do** have those files on my computer.

I tried to fix it myself, it was dumb but I copied those files over to the directory in which the program itself was.

P.S. here's the code but I don't think it matters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int rnum;
char yn;
srand (time(NULL));

cout << "Welcome to my fortune teller!!!"<< endl;
cout << "It uses an extremely futuristic and advanced algorithm!"<< endl;
cout << "if you know your luck, it can easily change, are you sure you want to continue? Y/N"<< endl;
cin >> yn;

if (yn == 'Y'){}
else if (yn == 'y'){}
else {
    return 0;
}


rnum = rand() % 11 + 1;

if (rnum == 1) {
    system("color A1");
    cout << "Bad luck, you're screwed mi friend"<< endl;
}
else if (rnum == 2) {
    cout << "Jump off of a building cuz' you got the lucks"<< endl;
}
else if (rnum == 3) {
    cout << "It's an awkward day for you, I see..."<< endl;
}
else if (rnum == 4) {
    cout << "Sorry man, go home and lock yourself into a closet"<< endl;
}
else if (rnum == 5) {
    cout << "Do risky things today, your luck has hit 100%"<< endl;
}
else if (rnum == 6) {
    cout <<"Quite frankly, I'm not sure, today looks kinda cloudy for you, the sun may shine through though"<< endl;
}
else if (rnum == 7) {
    cout << "Your luck is a bit more on the bad side, it could fix (by the end of the century)" << endl;
}
else if (rnum == 8) {
    cout << "Your luck is a bit on the good side, but don't do dumb things, it can easily fall into the bottomless sea" << endl;
}
else if (rnum == 9) {
    cout << "This is weird, it's balancing right in the middle, look out, it could go bad anytime, or good"<< endl;
}
else if (rnum == 10) {
    cout <<"No comment."<< endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: This means the mingw dlls are not in your system path. Update your system path to include the folder containing these dlls.

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: Basically, how to fix it

Comment: I will now try to see if it works with Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Fix what? This is expected behaviour. If you dynamically link to your C/C++ runtime you have to distribute the runtime along with your executable. Or install it on the system where it gets loaded when required. Code::Blocks environment searches special directories for these files. Regular Windows does not. for Visual Studio its similar - but the runtime gets installed with the Studio so you won't notice it on your machine. You can also statically link your runtime, for both, Visual Studio and Code:Blocks.

Comment: I know it is expected behaviour. What I was asking is if there was any way of compiling the .exe with the needed files. I don't need it anymore so don't say anything